# "This practice can disrupt the children´s privacy, even though parents are not enough aware of its danger."

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context

My EFL C1 (CEFR) students are writing an essay on the dangers of parents posting their children's picture on social media. One student wrote this sentence, it doesn't sound quite right, but I can't pinpoint what is wrong:

> This practice can disrupt the children´s privacy, even though parents are not enough aware of its danger.

Is it the placement of "enough" or "enough + aware"?

Comment: *This practice can **dangerously violate the privacy of children**, even **without the awareness of their** parents.*

Comment: Thanks Jason, that certainly sounds much more natural.

Comment: Alternatively, "...parents are not aware enough of its danger." "Enough" is more natural coming *after* the adjective "aware" than before it.

Comment: Thanks Rosie. I thought so.

Comment: Another alternative is "The practice can compromise the children's privacy but parents are insufficiently aware of it's danger". However I understand that "compromise" and "insufficiently" might be beyo

Comment: @JasonBassford Since it's an EFL class, not civics, we probably should avoid editorializing and just address the language issues.

Comment: I would say "even though the parents are not fully aware of its danger".

Answer (score 1):

> This practice can disrupt the children´s privacy, even though parents
> are not enough aware of its danger.

This sentence isn't problematic because of the use of *enough*, but because of the use of *even though*.

**even though** - In spite of (something).

Given this, the sentence doesn't make sense. The reason is that we *expect a negative outcome* if we aren't aware of some danger: disrupting children's privacy is such a negative outcome. Because we expect a negative outcome, we can't use "in spite of" or any of its synonyms. If the parents *were* aware of the danger, *then* we could use one of these terms.

Answer (score 0):

"enough" is an adverb that modifies "aware". While there are many exceptions, adverbs usually go after the word they modify, so it should be "aware enough" rather than "enough aware".

Also, "disrupt" is not an idiomatic word to describe what this does to privacy. As mentioned in the comments, more common terms are "compromise" and "violate". We usually use "compromise" when talking about systems (e.g. exploits compromise the security of computer systems), and "violate" when referring to people.

Comment: If one wishes to include adjective-modifiers with adverbs, they almost always go _before_ the adjective they're modifying. Very good. Extremely thin. Highly controversial. Pretty close. Frighteningly intelligent. Fiercely competitive. Deeply moving. Endlessly varied. Desperately poor....

Comment: Very good point, you're extremely observant and always helpful.

Comment: So why does the order flip in cases like this?

Comment: It's almost certainly an aberration evolving from some old phrasing involving a precursor of 'enough'. 'The synonym 'sufficiently aware' has the usual ordering.